# Is there a way to vectorize this matlab embedded for loop code?

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, vectorization

I had a code with nested `for`-loops

```
for a = 1:P
    for i = 1:p
        for j = 1:p
            A(C(a, i), C(a, j)) = A(C(a, i), C(a, j)) + M(i, j);
        end
    end
end
```

I managed to ameliorate the time complexity

```
i = 1:p;
j = 1:p;

for a = 1:P
   A(C(a, i), C(a, j)) = A(C(a, i), C(a, j)) + M(i, j);
end
```

However, I cannot use the same method for the last `for` loop because of array dimension errors. The constant `P` is also significantly larger than `p`, which makes the first `for` loop the most important to optimize.

How can I vectorise the last loop?

As an example of arbitrary values:

```
p = 2;
P = 5; 
A = sparse(P+1, P+1); % A is a 6x6 matrix here. Sparse since we do not expect many non-zeros
C = [1 3; 3 5; 5 2; 2 4; 4 6]; % Pxp matrix with largest term = P+1
M = [3 6; 8 3]; % pxp matrix
```

The result of the for loop should be:

```
A(C(1, 1:2), C(1, 1:2)) += M(1:2, 1:2);
A(C(2, 1:2), C(2, 1:2)) += M(1:2, 1:2);
.
.
.
A(C(5, 1:2), C(5, 1:2)) += M(1:2, 1:2);
```

Comment: Please include a small example defining `A`, `C`, `M`, `P`, `p` and the desired result

Comment: I hope the example I added made it somewhat clearer.

Comment: "I managed to ameliorate the time complexity" -- No, the time complexity is the same, the loops are still there, but not explicit. But you probably sped up the code a bit. It is possible to remove the last loop, but it will likely result in a slower program. Replacing `M(i, j)` with `M` might make things faster, unless the JIT is already doing that change for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized form:

```
[a, i, j] = ndgrid(1:P, 1:p, 1:p);
N = max(C(:));
ai = sub2ind([P, p], a, i);
aj = sub2ind([P, p], a, j);
ij = sub2ind([p, p], i, j);

A = sparse(C(ai), C(aj), M(ij), N, N);
```

However it may be less memory/processor efficient than the loop. As `P` is larger than `p`, You can only vectorize the outer loop:

```
A = sparse(N, N);
for i = 1:p
    for j = 1:p
        A = A + sparse(C(:, i), C(:, j), M(i, j), N, N);
    end
end
```

Use `accumarray` if the computations should be applied on dense array:

```
A = 0;
for i = 1:p
    for j = 1:p
        A = A + accumarray(C(:, [i j]), M(i, j), [N, N]);
    end
end
```